# Is there a UI tool for moving data from two different tables?

Tags: mysql, migration, tools

The schemas in the two databases are different. Eg.

Database 1 / users
- id
- name
- phone

Database 2 / users
- id
- first_name
- mobile

Is there a tool that lets me visually create the statements or do the transform / copying the data?

Using MySQL by the way :)

Comment: MySQL Workbench is the tool of choice when working with MySQL. You could also try SQuirreL SQL. You'll end up having to write SQL at the end of the day no matter which tool you choose as your GUI admin tool - INSERT INTO Database2 SELECT id, name, phone FROM Database1; for example. There's no way that you can just drop a database table from a GUI onto another one and expect the tool to figure out the mappings on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a UI tool when the query is this short?

```
INSERT INTO db1.users (id, name, phone)
    SELECT id, first_name, mobile FROM db2.users;
```

Caveats:  You probably should not copy `id` if it is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.  I was guessing which direction you wanted to copy.